# (R) Getting "variable length differ" for two different variable

Tags: r, dataset, anova

I created two variable called **"low.income"**  and **"mid.income"** from survey, they are variables which obtained based on participants income. here you can see the variables how looks like:

```
low.income = 75  95  85 100  85 100  85  90  75  90  65  80  85  90  85  70  95  85 100  95  85  95  90  95  95
```

mid.income = 95 100  90  90  85  95 100  95  80

But when try to call `aov(low.income~mid.income)` it gives me **Error in model.frame.default(formula = low.income ~ mid.income, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'mid.income')**

So, what should i do ?

Comment: Your formula states that low.income depends on mid.income. Do you have same number of values in both vectors so that it can relate each value of low.income with mid.income?

Comment: the error message is pretty self-explanatory: your `low.income` and `mid.income` need to be of equal length.

Comment: Yes guys, and I am looking to solution to make them both equal properly, or running t.test or ANOVA despite of this flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not correct, I think you are looking for `t.test` ie

```
 t.test(low.income, mid.income, var.equal = TRUE)
```

To use the formula method, you have to create a dataframe with the level and the income. It should look like below:

```
 data <-  data.frame(level = rep(paste0(c("low","mid"),".income"),c(25,9)), income = c(low.income,mid.income))

       level income
1 low.income     75
2 low.income     95
3 low.income     85
4 low.income    100
5 low.income     85
6 low.income    100
:    :           :
29 mid.income     90
30 mid.income     85
31 mid.income     95
32 mid.income    100
33 mid.income     95
34 mid.income     80
```

Now you could do:

```
t.test(income~level,data,var.equal = TRUE)
```

Well Since you are using `aov`, I will give you an example of how to do that:

```
aov(income~level,data)
```

These two will lead to the exact same result. You can run `TukeyHSD` to see that the results are the same.

NOTE: You only run ANOVA when you have more than 2 groups. If you only have 2 groups, run a `t.test`. Recall that `ANOVA` is a generalization of the `t.test`

Comment: Thank you sir ! It worked, preciated? Can you explain data variable more please ? I would like to completely understand how did you solve.

Comment: @MustafaSakalli Do you understand what anova is? If you do, then you will note that we are comparing means of groups. So each datapoint must be classified into one of the groups. Hence thats how the data is created. The first 25 data points are all low.income while the next 9 are mid income

Comment: Thank you very much.